# OWIN AuthenticationMiddleware invoked twice per request

Tags: .net, owin, middleware

I have a trouble while using owin cookie authentication middleware:

When I added cookie authentication middleware to my Startup.Configuration, all of my middlewares will invoke twice per request, and this is my code:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            // this code will be executed twice per http request
            return next();
        });

        // my cookie middleware
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
        });
    }
```

and then I writed a middleware myself which inherit from AuthenticationMiddleware with empty implement, and it's worked just the same -- all of my middlewares will invoke twice per request.

When I debugged the owin AuthenticationMiddleware source code:

```
 public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        AuthenticationHandler<TOptions> handler = CreateHandler();
        await handler.Initialize(Options, context);
        if (!await handler.InvokeAsync())
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        await handler.TeardownAsync();
    }
```

I found that `await Next.Invoke(context);` will cause all of my middlewares invoked again.

But when I use other middlewares(StaticFiles middleware, Webapi middleware), everything works fine.

Did I missed something about OWIN or AuthenticationMiddleware?

Why would my middleware invoked twice per request? Is it by design?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your application is in Owin, you should add this middleware to the end of your pipeline, and your problem should be gone!

```
app.Run(async context =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("404");
});
```

This will keep the request in the owin context, and it won't get to default IIS modules. For some reason (I don't know what!) if a request goes out of Owin and no module handle it, owin request would run twice!!

Comment: Yes, I found that I should handle the request in my last owin middleware. If no middlewares handle the request (and the last middleware return next(); ), all of my middlewares will be invoked again.